# Changing Github Repo Name - Possible Issues?

Tags: github

I have a question about working with Github.

Let's say I have a repo called 'WorkflowRepo' and I've done work on that repo already, but I have some unpushed changes on my local.

I subsequently changed the repo name to 'WorkflowRepoAnalysis' on Github

Will I be able to push these changes without any 'naming conflicts'? Because the repo is called 'WorkflowRepo' on my local but 'WorkflowRepoAnalysis' on Github.

Answer (score 0):

I tested out for the situation that you have mentioned. I was able to push local changes to the remote repo without any naming conflicts. The steps I followed are mentioned below.

1. Created a repo, let's say name `testRepo` and initialized with README.
2. Added changes to README via Github.
3. Cloned that repo on local machine and made some changes to the README.
4. Went to Github and renamed the repo to `testRepoNameChanged`.
5. Pushed the changed.

I faced no naming conflicts.

Additionally, the `git push` command does prompt this, but there are no conflicts. The local changes are reflected on remote.

```
remote: This repository moved. Please use the new location:
remote: https://github.com/username/testRepoNameChanged.git
```